# Increasing Parallelism of Foreach in pig

Tags: hadoop, foreach, apache-pig

I have a list of URLs that I want to iterate over, where each contains a particular file that I want to download. I'm trying to utilize hadoop/pig to speed up this process, thinking that having each node take care of a particular download/upload will help increase network throughput.

I have a UDF that takes care of the download, corruption check, upload, but I'm having issues finding a way to make this call non-blocking in a sense so that I can do multiple downloads at a particular time.. I started with a foreach calling the UDF for each URL, but it will just spawn one download task at a time. There are 2 tasks running each with a single mapper. There is one that is running the foreach loop, and another that is running the UDF. Each UDF is an isolated task, as each file part is logically a separate download. Any idea if its possible to make this more parallel? I'm not sure if increasing the number of mappers would be cause this UDF to be non-blocking..

The file sizes i'm dealing with are around 2.8 GB a piece, I'm dealing with around 1 TB a day

Any help or suggestions to investigate would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use KafKa for your situation. It is a Apache Project. It can handle hundreds of megabytes of reads and writes per second from thousands of clients.

It has two entity one is Known as Producer who inputs your data to Kafka and another is called as Consumer which reads data from Kafka.

You can implement your client which downloads data from URL as your producer. If you want to Process the data that you can use storm and register it as consumer.

Or you can use KafKa and Hadoop API to register Hadoop as consumer to Kafka.